# Running BigQuery load job on app engine gets stuck in pending state

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I am trying to load data into BigQuery and the load job stays in the pending state indefinitely (I waited about 5 minutes). Is there something else I need to be doing to move the job to a running state?

```
log.log(new LogRecord(Level.INFO, "Writing to big query table"));
JobConfigurationLoad loadConf = new JobConfigurationLoad();
loadConf.setDestinationTable(new TableReference().setProjectId(PROJECT_ID)
    .setDatasetId(datasetId).setTableId(TABLE_ID));
loadConf.setWriteDisposition("WRITE_APPEND");
loadConf.setSourceUris(Arrays.asList("gs://" + bucket + "/" + "something.json"));
JobConfiguration configuration = new JobConfiguration().setLoad(loadConf);
Job loadJob = new Job().setConfiguration(configuration);
Jobs.Insert insertData = bigQuery.jobs().insert(PROJECT_ID, loadJob);
Job insertResp = insertData.execute();

JobStatus status = insertResp.getStatus();
    while (!status.getState().equals("done")) {
        System.out.println(status.getState());
        status = insertResp.getStatus();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
}
...
```

Comment: Import requested are queued by BigQuery. We have an experience than importing took about 1 hour. So try to wait more. You should use Task API or backends to monitor such kind of work, because of timeouts for requests and tasks.

Comment: Can you send the job ID of a job that got stuck in a pending state?

Comment: pogoapps.com:pogoapps:job_9c2f67bee94342f397daa07fcb004568

Comment: According to our logs this job was only pending for 16 seconds.

Comment: I ran that one locally and am pretty sure it was pending for atleast 5 mins. This one I ran on the GAE server for many hours before getting this error. 2012-12-22 08:15:28.507 Uncaught exception from servlet com.google.apphosting.runtime.HardDeadlineExceededError: This request (56545609c4cb8d99) started at 2012/12/21 16:15:3

Comment: Do you mean this line? Job insertResp = insertData.execute();  Won't this re-run the insert operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the problem of not getting the latest job results, this code should work (if you add to what you had above:

```
// Insert the load job.
Job job = insertData.execute();  
JobId jobId = job.getJobId();

long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

while (!job.getStatus().getState().equals("DONE")) {
   // Pause execution for ten seconds before polling job status again
   Thread.sleep(10000);

   long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
   System.out.format("Job status (%dms) %s: %s\n", elapsedTime,
       jobId.getJobId(), job.getStatus().getState());       

   // Poll the server for job completion state.
   job = bigquery.jobs().get(projectId, jobId).execute();
}
if (job.getStatus().getErrorResult() != null) {
  // The job ended with an error.
  System.out.format("Job %s ended with error %s", job.getJobId(), 
      job.getStatus().getErrorResult().getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've dug into this somewhat, and the issue is that you did 2300 import jobs to the same table, adding a new one every few seconds. The jobs started to get queued, since the new ones were arriving faster than they could be processed. This caused longer and longer pending times. It looks like the large number of jobs may have been unintentional, since they all seemed to be importing the same file to the same table. Incidentally, jobs all failed with an invalid_value error.

Note that this pattern only happened on 12/20. Other than this date I couldn't find any other jobs that you ran that lasted longer than 10 minutes.

Comment: I was running this keyed off a TaskQueue with a 5 minute lease so its possible they were run multiple times. If the job did not complete in 5 minutes. I ran another Job today from local host, took out the task queue code and it is still pending after 15 mins.
Jan 3, 2013 3:22:48 PM WARNING: Job: {"jobId":"job_fe52dd008e2e4346a5d7b1c4249050d0","projectId":"pogoapps.com:pogoapps"} is still pending

Comment: 2 issues. The code you specified above doesn't actually re-check the bigquery server for the job status -- it just keeps looking at the local status which would never change. You need to redo the execute operation.

Comment: Second issue: you are doing a json import but not specifying the json format. You should set sourceFormat to NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON.

Comment: Do you mean "insertData.execute();" this line? Won't this re-apply the update?

Comment: I didn't read it carefully. You should poll for results as in https://developers.google.com/bigquery/articles/gettingstartedwithjava under the section "Poll the BigQuery API for the Query Result"

Comment: Following steps in the article I get Job pogoapps.com:pogoapps:job_8649d2a3e26248d4be64f9ab30d98475 is not a query job. Is there an equivalent tutorial for load jobs.

Comment: The part where it gets the query results won't work (e.g. under the heading "Retrieve and Display Query Results"), but the part under the heading "Poll the BigQuery API for the query result" should work for any job type. It just does a Get() operation on the job. I've updated my answer above to include the code.